# Graphic novel about girl with white hair and shadow magic

Tags: story-identification, graphic-novel

Don't remember most of the concept but I know that it was a graphic novel style. I read it back in middle school in the early 2000's Girl had white hair and some sort of magic to do with shadows.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the girl herself magical?